# flask-sqlalchemy distinct + where returns empty set

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database that contains columns `commune` and `liste`.  These fields are not null, so any query that selects one with a WHERE constraint on the other ought to succeed.  (In the example below, I've confirmed that it does succeed as raw SQL.)

If I write this:

```
communes = db.session.query(SurveyResponder.commune.distinct()).all()
```

I get a list of distinct commune values.  If I then take one of those values and write

```
commune = communes[0][0]    # The extra dereference just copes with all() returning tuples.
lists = db.session.query(SurveyResponder.liste.distinct()).filter_by(commune=commune).all()
```

I get an empty result set:

```
[('',)]
```

If I look at the SQL generated,

```
db.session.query(SurveyResponder.liste.distinct()).filter_by(commune=commune)
```

I see this SQL emitted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT survey_responder.liste AS anon_1 
FROM survey_responder 
WHERE survey_responder.commune = ?
```

If I replace the ? with a real argument from the communes results, I see results:

```
$ sqlite3 dev.db 
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT survey_responder.liste AS anon_1 
   ...> FROM survey_responder 
   ...> WHERE survey_responder.commune = 'Vertou';
Vertou naturellement
Vertou’S
Soyons Vertou

sqlite>
```

I suspect I've made some goofy syntax error, but I'm not finding it.  Any pointers?

Comment: `[('',)]` is not empty. It is a result of 1 row of 1 column of string, which then happens to be a 0 length string.

Comment: Aha, you are quite right.  And, while that column can't be null, it can, apparently, be empty.  Which it almost never is (and shouldn't be, but the data came from humans), except that it was on the two examples I was playing with.  Thanks!